# Задача на использование конструкции switch

Tags: java, switch

товарищи, не могу решить задачу:
Дано целое число в диапазоне 100 – 999. Вывести строку — словесное описание данного числа, например: 256 — "двести пятьдесят шесть", 814 — "восемьсот четырнадцать". Будьте добры, помогите с решением, заранее премного благодарен.

Comment: Что тут решать-то. Пишешь свитч на 899 веток и профит!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решаете задачу рекурсивно вычетая напечатанное.

856 = восемьсот + 56 = восемьсот + пятьдесят + 6 = восемьсот пятьдесят шесть

на сотнях

если 100 - сто

если 200 - двести

....

если 900 - девятьсот

десятках

если 10 - десять

если 11 - одиннадцать

если 12 - двенадцать

если 13 - тринадцать

...

если 20 - двадцать

если 30 - тридцать

....

если 90 - девяносто

единицы
1 - один

2 - два

..

9 - девять

удачи

Comment: большое спасибо!

Comment: @EMFO если помогло то пометить не забудьте